Order Modififer
Is there any way or addon in Blender that can add priority to modifiers?
Example:
1 object - 8 modifiers
2 object - 4 modifiers
1 object:
4 modifiers with Order 0
4 modifiers with Order 2
2 object:
4 modifiers with Order 1

First 4 modifiers with order 0 are triggered at 1 object,
4 modifiers are triggered for 2 objects in Order 1,
Triggers 4 modifiers with Order 2 for 1 object


modifiers are ordered from top to bottom, if you want to change "priority" just reorder the modifiers

I understand that, but I'm talking about the order of modifiers triggering on different objects, so that first 4 modifiers triggered on 1 object, then 4 modifiers on 2 objects and the remaining modifiers on 1 object triggered

I suspect you might mean something different by "objects" than most of us here mean. Every object has its own, unique, modifier stack. But perhaps you mean something like instances, mesh islands or something similar instead.

No, it is not possible.
The thing that you are asking for is called "Dependency Graph". Blender decides the order of execution by itself using internal algorithms, based on dependencies.
For example, if an object #1 has a boolean modifier with an object #2, #2 will execute before #1, to have ready to use in boolean. If you want to make an #2⇾#1⇾#2 dependency, it will be a dependency cycle, that will cause issues, so it counts as error.
Blender has no API to make changes in Dependency Graph
But: you can get more control using Geometry Nodes. For example, you can make object #3, create GN tree in #3, get #1 and #2 objects and combine them. Then continue modifier stack in object #3 after GN modifier.
